# Android Lollipop - PackageInstaller.Session commit()

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-package-managers, android-install-apk, packageinstaller

I'm trying to install packages on my device (from a device-owner app that runs on it) only by using the PackageInstaller and PackageManager APIs. I have been looking for examples but couldn't find anything that fit my need.

Here is a sample of my code to install the Facebook app:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInstaller mPackageInstaller = pm.getPackageInstaller();
PackageInstaller.SessionParams mSessionParams = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);

mSessionParams.setReferrerUri(Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/Facebook.apk"));
int mSessionId = mPackageInstaller.createSession( mSessionParams );

PackageInstaller.Session mPkgSession = PackageInstaller.openSession(mSessionId);
OutputStream mOStream = mPkgSession.openWrite("com.facebook.katana", 0, -1);
mPkgSession.fsync(mOStream);
```

I guess, the next function I need to launch is a "commit(IntentSender statusReceiver)".

So Please tell me how to use commit() and especially how to declare a proper IntentSender to install the APK which is stored in /sdcard.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 5):

This is possible from Android 6.0 and up.

- Make your app the Device owner.

Once your app gets the Device owner permission, we can install, uninstall and update silently without any user intervention.

```
public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream in, String packageName)
        throws IOException {
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set params
    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
    PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
    OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    session.fsync(out);
    in.close();
    out.close();

    session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
    return true;
}
```

Uninstall:

```
String appPackage = "com.your.app.package";
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), getActivity().getClass());
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
PackageInstaller mPackageInstaller = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
mPackageInstaller.uninstall(appPackage, sender.getIntentSender());
```

Comment: can i update a app2 from app1 by using this functionality through OTA(Over The Air) ?

Comment: Yes sir. @beginner. In fact, there is an example on github that does the same(testdpc on github)..  There is a guide as well.. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cosu/#0

Comment: The whole code is running without errors..but I could not see the app installed in my device.

Comment: @sandeep ? if you run this code, your app will be uninstalled. So its working as expected right? am i missing something

Comment: I am trying the installPackage method.. I gave admin permission to the app and its a system app now. but this method does not work. there is no app installed.

Comment: One the app receives admin permission, it becomes a device owner app, not a system app. I cannot figure out what could be the reason without seeing ur code. Can you post some gist on github? @sandeep

Answer (score 1):

So after a few days looking for a way to use a IntentSender, I figured out that it is actually contained in a PendingIntent.

Here is a code that can be used:

```
Intent coucou = new Intent(this, ReceivedCommitActivity.class);
coucou.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent pCoucou = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, coucou,0);
IntentSender mIntentSender = pCoucou.getIntentSender();

mPkgSession.commit(mIntentSender);
```